# НЕ получается импортировать проект WP из хостинга на свой локальный сервер

Tags: php, wordpress

Выдает логи апача показывают такую  ошибку:

```
[Tue Mar 28 12:08:28.633493 2017] [:error] [pid 5010] [client 127.0.0.1:53108] PHP Warning:  Declaration of iconNavs_Edit_Nav_Menu_Walker::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = Array, $id = 0) in /var/www/projects/test.php.com/www/wp-content/plugins/iconic-navigation/iconavs_menu_fun.php on line 0
==> /var/log/apache2/access.log <==
127.0.0.1 - - [28/Mar/2017:12:08:25 +0300] "GET /www/ HTTP/1.1" 404 34308 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
```

Нашел этот файл,но мне он ни о чем не сказал....0 строка...и 404 nоt found... подскажите куда копать или кто сталкивался с перебрасыванием проекта из хостинга на свой локальный сервер

Comment: Первое сообщение - всего лишь предупреждение, можно игнорировать. Вторая - не найдена папка /www/. Опишите подробно, что вы делали, и что видите в браузере, в том числе в его консоли.

Comment: я скачал проект из хостинга, перенес его в папку своего локального проекта, дал права (делаю на убунту сейчас). в браузере отображается сайт частично, но в одной части вместо текста оригинала пишется  Not Found

Apologies, but the page you requested could not be found. Perhaps searching will help

Comment: Если настроек у `iconic-navigation` не очень много - попробуйте переустановить плагин и вручную перенастроить его

Comment: там код 400 строк...

Comment: При чем тут код? Я говорю про настройки плагина в админке ВП

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно поменять названия таблиц:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
```

П.С.: более детально написано по этой ссылке

Comment: это 1) замена НЕ названий таблиц, а данных в них. 2) неправильный способ. Правильный я указал неделю назад и пояснил почему правильно/неправильно.

Answer (score 2):

> подскажите куда копать

Начать с отключения плагина  iconic-navigation.

Но кроме того перенос сайта нужно выполнять правильно, а не простым копирование файлов и базы с заменой в ней домена.
Правильно - это так, чтобы были исправлены сериализованные данные. Наиболее просто более-менее корректную миграцию осуществить с пом. плагинов. Напр. https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Или же исправить пути к файлам(!) и домены с пом. скрипта https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

**АПД**. Хотя последнее обновление этого плагина было 18 месяцев назад, но по факту же не менее  3лет назад. В последней версии [были изменены только цифры версии.](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/changeset/1260439/) Думаю, стоит найти ему актуальную альтернативу.